# pod install is not working when I try to set up SDWebImage

Tags: ios, cocoapods

This is really frustrating me I have no idea what the problem is. This is my first time trying to use cocoapods. I "pod init" in my project folder, then after I "pod install" here is the error I get:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qZ56.png)

Here is what I have my Podfile edited to:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Bulpy' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Bulpy
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'

  target 'BulpyTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'BulpyUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Here is a link to SDWebImage:
[link to SDWebImage on Github](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Please help. I could not find anything online regarding this issue :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error.
My CocoaPod version is 1.0.0 and it gave me the same error, for SDWebImage for version 3.8 .
So I removed the version number(just kept 'SDWebImage' ), and did a pod install and it installed with the version 3.76

My assumption is SDWebImage version 3.8 doesn't work on CocoaPods version 1.0.0 .

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`SDWebImage` does not have a v3.8 available yet with cocoapods. See [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), the pod version available atm is 3.7.6

[image]

Comment: Where do you see that? When I scroll down to "Installation with CocoaPods", it says 3.8 :S

Comment: I see. Even when I change it to 3.76 it still gives me the same error =/

Comment: Did you do a `pod repo update` like the error message suggests?

Comment: I did it prior to doing "pod install"

Comment: This is probably a really stupid question. Do I need a github account myself or git to accomplish this? Could the fact that I don't have git be causing this problem?

Comment: You don't need a github account, but yes you do need git (which Xcode would have installed for you). Check your git version `git --version` and make sure it is not outdated (I have 2.8.2). Try cleaning your derived data and doing a  pod install again?

Comment: Also when/if you run `pod repo update`, run with the `--verbose` argument. That gives more helpful logs

Comment: I have git version 2.8.1 so I will update it. How do I clean derived data? Just delete the Podfile and folders relating to Pods in the project folder? Off the top of your head do you know the command to update git through terminal? Actually according to the git site 2.8.1 is the latest maintained build so should I stay there? :S

Comment: If it means anything, I created a test project and was able to successfully "install pod" with Alamofire pod

Comment: I was also able to install the Alamofire pod into my current project too (just tested). So it seems to be a problem with the SDWebImage pod..